# Copying a chart (including the specific format) and pasting it onto a worksheet using VBA, changing the data range current worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a button that will copy a chart that I've named master_chart and paste it onto multiple worksheets. i'm starting with 1 and the issue i'm having is changing the data range once it's been pasted onto the new worksheet. also the format isn't exactly the same as i have to change the legend size. At the moment the 1st chart data range is almost correct but it's missing the x-axis labels and I've tried

```
' Set the x-axis labels range
chtNew.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels = rngData1.Rows(1).Resize(, rngData1.Columns.Count)
```

But I get an error 'Object doesn't support this property method' run time error 438'

My code below:

```
Sub DuplicateMasterChart()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim chtSource As ChartObject
    Dim chtNew As ChartObject
    Dim rngData1 As Range
    Dim rngData2 As Range
    
    ' Set the source worksheet (Company 1)
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Company 1")
    
    ' Set the destination worksheet (Company 2)
    Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Company 2")
    
    ' Set the source chart (master_chart)
    Set chtSource = wsSource.ChartObjects("master_chart")
    
    ' Duplicate the chart twice
    chtSource.Copy
    wsDestination.Paste
    wsDestination.Paste
    
    ' Get the newly pasted charts
    Set chtNew = wsDestination.ChartObjects(wsDestination.ChartObjects.Count)
    
    ' Rename the duplicated charts
    chtNew.Name = "duplicated_chart1"
    Set chtNew = wsDestination.ChartObjects(wsDestination.ChartObjects.Count - 1)
    chtNew.Name = "duplicated_chart2"
    
    ' Set the data range for the first chart
    Set rngData1 = wsDestination.Range("A17:R25")
    chtNew.Chart.SetSourceData rngData1
    
' Set the data range for the chart, excluding the series labels
chtNew.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rngData1.Offset(1).Resize(rngData1.Rows.Count - 1)


' Set the x-axis labels range
chtNew.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels = rngData1.Rows(1).Resize(, rngData1.Columns.Count)



    
    ' Set the data range for the second chart
    Set rngData2 = wsDestination.Range("A30:R38")
    chtNew.Chart.SetSourceData rngData2
End Sub
```

I just need help setting the data range correctly.

Comment: "But I get an error." What is the error?

Comment: For a contiguous range, `rngData1.Rows(1).Resize(, rngData1.Columns.Count)` is the same as `rngData1.Rows(1)`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad 'Object doesn't support this property method' run time error 438

Comment: @TimWilliams the data range isn't contiguous as it's all on different worksheets but the first range starts at row 17, the 2nd range starts at row 30. the height and width varies across the sheets

Comment: I don't think you can use a non-contiguous range for that.

Comment: @TimWilliams Ah so data all needs to be on the same sheet? But my issue isnt that the graphs aren't being created it's that the formating isn't properly being applied. the graphs are create and then pasted on the different sheets but when i change the data range to the one on the sheet the formatting is lost.